# php afnetworking upload image

Tags: php, image, upload, afnetworking

I am new to PHP. Currently, I am trying to write an iOS app and upload an image from this app using AFNetworking.

I have a PHP file like this. I can upload the image from iPad's Safari browser to my local host. However, I can't upload from my iOS app. How should I do it?

### PHP Code

```
<?php
//print_r($_FILES);
if(isset($_FILES['image']))
{
    $errors=array();
    $allowed_ext= array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif');
    $file_name =$_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_ext = strtolower( end(explode('.',$file_name)));

    //print_r($file_ext);

    $file_size=$_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    if(in_array($file_ext,$allowed_ext) === false)
    {
        $errors[]='Extension not allowed';
    }

    if($file_size > 2097152)
    {
        $errors[]= 'File size must be under 2mb';

    }
    if(empty($errors))
    {
       if( move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, 'images/'.$file_name));
       {
        echo 'File uploaded';
       }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach($errors as $error)
        {
            echo $error , '<br/>'; 
        }
    }
   //  print_r($errors);

}
?>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<p>
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">

</p>
</form>
```

### iOS code

```
-(void)uploadFile
{

    NSLog(@"gona upload image");
    NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.11.7/uploadimage"];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient= [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

    NSData *imageData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_2480.jpg"], 0.5);

    //NSLog(@"imageData is %@",imageData);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/images" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"IMG_2480.jpg" fileName:@"IMG_2480.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    }];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
        NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes",totalBytesWritten,totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
    }];

    [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];

}
```

Comment: You are initializing with the URL `http://192.168.11.7/uploadimage`, and then overriding that with the path `/images`, which will result in a path `http://192.168.11.7/images`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Also, you should set success and failure blocks on your `operation` object so you can see any errors the server is sending you.

Comment: I need to upload image in http://192.168.11.7/uploadimage/images. How should I change

Comment: remove the `/` in `@"/images"`

Comment: Thanks bro. it is now closer. The directory is correct now. But I still cannot upload image. You and other people have said that I am uploading as "imageData" and my form accept "image". Can you please help how to change that one to successfully upload?

Comment: I said the opposite of that.

Comment: Yes. How should I write correctly?

Answer (score 1):

There is propably naming problem, check your code here:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/images" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
[formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"IMG_2480.jpg" fileName:@"IMG_2480.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];
```

Your form accepts "image" field in posted data, youre sending it as "imageData"

Comment: Isn't `imageData` just the pointer to the NSData object?  Where do you see the string "imageData" being sent to the server?

Comment: Thanks. So, how should I write there? Can you please give a line of code?